# Retrieve data from database and display minimum line in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Actually I want to get a product descriptions of 5 lines, which is totally 10 lines in database and display in html. OR get 10 lines of products description and display only 5 lines in html.

Comment: Share your code that you have done yet?

Comment: Actually I didn't do it yet. Just planning on it

Comment: Thanks for your comment..Ok I will post here when I got stuck while coding

Answer (score 0):

you can't get thing by line you need to use character instead for example select first 100 character of that column there is two way of doing that

mysql :

```
SELECT name, substring(description,1,100), price FROM DatabaseName.product
```

php :

```
$description = substr($data['description'],0,99);
```

check how may characters you have in 5 line 
i recommend to do this in database layer php take too much process for this kind of thing